# HttpClient - How to set Headers uploading file?

Tags: java, httpclient

How to set header with HttpClient? Is there a standard code example?

Andrew

Comment: You mean the Apache HttpClient (http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/)?

Answer (score 1):

How about using [setHeader](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/message/AbstractHttpMessage.html#setHeader%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)...

```
httpRequest.setHeader(headerName, headerValue);
```

Comment: Emm... And could you show the whole code? httpRequest - is it a client side?

Comment: What more do you need? That's all there is to it. If this doesn't make sense then you need to ask a more general how-do-I-use-HttpClient question. Without knowing what else you want I can't possibly provide more code.

Comment: I need client to set header :) But as I can see req means a servlet code isn't it?

Comment: At this point, I'm lost. This will do what you asked. I don't know where servlets came into the picture.

Comment: Emm... is AbstractHttpMessage setHeader("","")  better than HttpPost httppost.addHeader("","") ?

Comment: I couldn't find example showing AbstractHttpMessage header demo :(